# React not updating its state when come back using react-router in Apollo Client

Tags: reactjs, react-router, graphql, apollo

I am trying to implement a scenario where I need to add a new site, and take to site listing page back and it needs to fetch new updated records. I am right now using Apollo client with ReactJS and GraphQL.

This is my siteListContainer page.

```
export default class SitesGrid extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    try {
      let sites = this.props.data.viewer.sites.edges;

      if (sites.length > 0 ) {
        sites = sites.map(item => item.node);
        return (
          <GridView>
            {sites.map(this.renderSiteCard)}
          </GridView>
        );
      }

    } catch (e) {
      console.info('There was an error fetching sites.');
    }

    return (<div />);
  }
}
```

Add Site form

```
class SiteForm extends React.Component {

  // Form on submit
  onSubmit(event) {
      //mutation to create site
      this.props.mutate({
        variables: variables
      }).then(() => {
        browserHistory.push('/app/device-explorer');        
      });
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

        <ListViewItem>
          <label>Site Name</label>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control"
                 aria-describedby="name" placeholder="Site Name"/>
        </ListViewItem>

        <ListViewItem className="text-xs-right">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </ListViewItem>

      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default (
  graphql(SiteSaveMutation)(
    graphql(SiteTypeQuery)(
      (SiteForm)
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In GraphQL, it's hard to tell which queries need to be refetched after a mutation automatically, so you need to tell Apollo what to do.

The easiest way to achieve this is to set the `cache-and-network` [fetch policy](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api.html#graphql-query-options.fetchPolicy) in your query container, then it will refetch whenever you go back (by default, it uses the cache). That would look like:

```
export default (
  graphql(SiteSaveMutation)(
    graphql(SiteTypeQuery, { options: { fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network' } })(
      (SiteForm)
    )
  )
);
```

You can also use [refetchQueries](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api.html#graphql-mutation-options.refetchQueries) or [updateQueries](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api.html#graphql-mutation-options.updateQueries).